Error mapping Optional JSON to RealmSwift @Persisted
Issue: There are two different objects within the array I am attempting to map and store into a RealmSwift database. However this parameter (@Persisted var folderItems: List) which is optional and only appears for the 'folder' type causes an error. All other data is mapped correctly.
Error: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.
Would anyone be able to resolve this so that the 'items' gets mapped when present?
Developer Note:
@Persisted var folderItems: List?
Is not valid, results in error: Generic struct 'Persisted' requires that 'List' conform to '_PersistableInsideOptional'
JSON:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "8e467944-00b8-11ef-ba84-0edd649d5685",
      "thumbnail": "https://sample.com",
      "position": "z",
      "updated_at": 1713797931000,
      "translations": [
        {
          "title": "This Carousel has a folder with a bunch of media",
          "id": "en_US"
        }
      ],
      "type": "carousel",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "9fadb738-00b8-11ef-9c82-0edd649d5685",
          "thumbnail": "https://sample.com",
          "position": "aa",
          "updated_at": 1713797842000,
          "translations": [
            {
              "title": "Folder that has a bunch of media items",
              "id": "en_US"
            }
          ],
          "type": "folder",
          "parent_id": "8e467944-00b8-11ef-ba84-0edd649d5685",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "2782c91c-fc24-11ee-ac56-0edd649d5685",
              "type": "video",
              "position": "gggggggggh",
              "updated_at": 1713797886000,
              "translations": [
                {
                  "title": "Deadpool & Wolverine",
                  "description": null,
                  "thumbnail": "https://sample.com",
                  "external_resource_id": "Jjsy0jnrTvWo7N9NQlFQ_Deadpool  Wolverine  Official Teaser  In Theaters July 26.mp4",
                  "id": "en_US",
                  "original": "https://sample.com"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2100f7d8-fb5e-11ee-a915-0edd649d5685",
          "type": "photo",
          "position": "p",
          "updated_at": 1713797939000,
          "translations": [
            {
              "title": "Chevy Convertible",
              "description": null,
              "thumbnail": "https://sample.com",
              "external_resource_id": "mPrEUiKRXOHdcVJXVBwX_chevy.jpeg",
              "id": "en_US",
              "original": "https://sample.com",
              "large": "https://sample.com"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Classes

public class Carousel: SynchronizedBase, Codable {

    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id = UUID().uuidString

    @Persisted var carouselId: String
    @Persisted var thumbnail: String?
    @Persisted var titleTranslations: List<Translation>
    @Persisted var position: String?
    @Persisted var lastUpdatedAt: Int?
    @Persisted var type: String?
    @Persisted var items: List<CarouselMedia>
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case carouselId = "id"
        case thumbnail
        case titleTranslations = "translations"
        case position
        case lastUpdatedAt = "updated_at"
        case type
        case items

    }

}

public class CarouselMedia: SynchronizedBase, Codable {

    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id = UUID().uuidString

    @Persisted var mediaId: String
    @Persisted var type: String?
    @Persisted var lastUpdatedAt: Int?
    @Persisted var position: String?
    @Persisted var translations: List<Translation>
     
    //Folder Specific
    @Persisted var parentCarouselId: String?
    @Persisted var thumbnail: String?
    @Persisted var folderItems: List<CarouselMedia>

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       
        case mediaId = "id"
        case type
        case thumbnail
        case translations
        case lastUpdatedAt = "updated_at"
        case parentCarouselId = "parent_id"
        case position
        case folderItems = "items"

    }
}

public class Translation: Object, Codable {

    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id = UUID().uuidString

    @Persisted var localizationId: String?//en_US
    @Persisted var title: String?
    @Persisted var desc: String?
    @Persisted var thumbnail: String?
    @Persisted var externalResourceId: String?

    @Persisted var original: String?
    @Persisted var large: String? //Still needed?

    @Persisted var needsDownload: Bool = true
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case localizationId = "id"
        case title
        case desc = "description"
        case thumbnail
        case externalResourceId = "external_resource_id"

        case original
        case large

    }
}


Without going too deep, you're likely running into a naming conflict with Swift with the List as it exists both in Swift as well as Realm. Just precede the property with RealmSwift. e.g. change @Persisted var translations: List<Translation> to  @Persisted var translations: RealmSwift.List<Translation>. Also folderItems is not optional in this case, nor should it be. See Supported Types

Adding RealmSwift.List doesn't resolve the issue as the compiler is able to resolve the class name. folderItems isn't optional and I am unable to make it optional as RealmSwift declares all Lists as empty and not optional.

That conflict with List is a known issue in SwiftUI which is why I mentioned it. Your question states (@Persisted var folderItems: List) which is optional - my comment was pointing out Lists are NOT optional in Realm, glad you saw that.

Added to the CarouselMedia class:
    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        mediaId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .mediaId)
        type = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        lastUpdatedAt = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .lastUpdatedAt)
        translations = try container.decode(List<Translation>.self, forKey: .translations)
        parentCarouselId = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .parentCarouselId)
        thumbnail = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .thumbnail)
        position = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .position)

        let items = try? container.decode(List<CarouselMedia>.self, forKey: .folderItems)
        folderItems = items ?? List<CarouselMedia>()
    }

    override required init() {
        super.init()
    }

Credit: Durgesh Trivedi

Not sure if all of that is necessary - perhaps it is? Please see my comment to the question. One thing though - that's not a correct initializer for a Realm object - assuming SynchronizedBase is a Realm object. It requires a convenience init along with a self.init call as it's an NSObject. See the Realm Person object here for an example

SynchronizedBase has a few other variables that are shared with some other classes. But yes it is of type RealmSwift's "Object". These should have been omitted but the issue would still appear with it removed. Thanks for the link

Adding just a "convenience init" instead of the decoder didn't resolve the issue

I am confused. Did you post this code because it's an answer? If not, it should not be posted as one and should be added to the question. If it is, great! But adding context as to what it does is best practice here on SO. I was not suggesting to just add a convenience init. The code is not correct and will not work correctly for Realm objects - they cannot be initialized in this fashion and doing this will override and bypass needed initializers Realm objects require.
